# How can I define TikZ style programatically?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm new to TeX and faced with syntax errors. Could you please tell me how can I solve the following problems?

#### ERROR 1

I want to define a pair of key and value in a command (or variable is easy for me) and put to style. Is it possible?

#### ERROR 2

I want to switch color by passing a boolean argument to `\choosecolor` . What's the cause of this error?

#### Code

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\red{red}
\newcommand*\fillgreen{fill=green}
\newcommand*\choosecolor[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{orange}{green}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\tikzset{pstyle/.style={fill=\red}};
\node[pstyle] (char) {RED};
}\par
%% === ERROR 1 ===
% \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
% \tikzset{pstyle/.style={\fillgreen}};
% \node[pstyle] (char) {GREEN};
% }\par
%% === ERROR 2 ===
% \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
% \tikzset{pstyle/.style={fill=\choosecolor{true}}};
% \node[pstyle] (char) {CHOOSE COLOR};
% }\par
\end{document}
```

[Run on Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/mqfbysknxbrj)

Comment: Why did you comment out so many lines? I suggest to comment out only those ones, which cause your errors, so we can copy, run and check more easily. Thanks

Comment: Is it really incomprehensible? For example "ERROR 1" corresponds from line 11-15 and if you uncomment these lines you can reproduce error (please refer to the link to Overleaf to see line number). Thanks

Comment: I'll have a look. However, you are suggesting that even the statement `\tikz{} `fails ?

Comment: I'm not sure which exact line causes error. I just separated statements `\tikz{}` because I want to use so.

Comment: Done, kindly see my answer below.

Comment: I am not sure what you want. Do you want a style that changes color following a setting of a global variable/switch, or a style with an argument, or a couple of styles defined globally?

Comment: Tikz style can have arguments like in e.g.`\tikzset{mystyle/.style={color=#1}}` to used as on `\node[mystyle=red] (NAME) {TEXT};`

Comment: @Rmano I know that it's not practical but leaving it aside, I want to know a correct syntax using `\fillgreen` and `\choosecolor` if it's possible.

Comment: @Jhor Already tried, but thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *still* think that this is an XY problem; you should use the native ways of `\pgfkeys` to have a variable style (there are a lot of options, but I do not understand exactly what you are up to...).

Anyway, the problem you have is that you have an expansion problem. Once `\tikzset` read its argument, it expands macros, but then, once the macros are expanded, it will *not* try again to split it. So in your second case, it is seeing a *key* called `/tikz/fill=green` and not a key `/tikz/fill` with argument `green`. Look at the error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/fill=green' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

In the second case, the `\ifthenelse` usage is wrong (there is not a constant `true`) and also it's not expandable, so you have to use a native if (I am using 1 for orange and 0 for green).

Basically you have to expand your command by hand:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\red{red}
\newcommand*\fillgreen{fill=green}
\newcommand*\choosecolor[1]{\ifnum#1=1 orange\else green\fi}
\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
\tikzset{pstyle/.style={fill=\red}}
\node[pstyle] (char) {RED};
}\par
%% === ERROR 1 ===
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
     \edef\tmp{pstyle/.style={\fillgreen}}
     \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\tmp}
 \node[pstyle] (char) {GREEN};
 }\par
 

%% === ERROR 2 ===
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
      \edef\tmp{pstyle/.style={fill=\choosecolor{1}}}
      \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{\tmp}
 \node[pstyle] (char) {CHOOSE COLOR};
 }\par
\end{document}
```

to obtain:

[image: output]

BTW, you have a lot of excess `;`, see the warnings:

```
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!
```

So you need to do magic with expansions.

As a native alternative (but there are more possibilities, again, it depends on what you really want):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\colorA{orange}
\newcommand\colorB{green}
\tikzset{choosecolor/.is choice,
    choosecolor/true/.style={color=\colorA},
    choosecolor/false/.style={color=\colorB},
}

\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)] \node[choosecolor=true] (char) {ORANGE};

\tikz[baseline=(char.base)] \node[choosecolor=false] (char) {GREEN};
\end{document}
```

[image: output from the code above]

Comment: Nice answer. One addition: Expansion could also be handled with `.expanded`, e.g. `\tikzset{pstyle/.style/.expanded={\fillgreen}}`, right?

Comment: Could be, I didn't try... ;-)

Comment: More than perfect answer! This is what I wanted and the last code is fairly smart. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

So, I located the lines, which actually do fail, and included a usual way to do it, with local scope. For the RED-case it seems to be related to the way `tikz` expands the macro. For the GREEN-case I suspect you are missing a variable, i.e. a memory place to store your choice.

Frankly, I don't see the advantage of your approach, unless there is a bigger picture to it.

[image: demonstrating an alternative way of styling]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\red{red}
\newcommand*\fillgreen{fill=green}
\newcommand*\choosecolor[1]{\ifthenelse{\boolean{#1}}{orange}{green}}

\begin{document}
\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \tikzset{pstyle/.style={fill=\red}};
    \node[pstyle] (char) {RED};
}

%% === ERROR 1 ===
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
 \tikzset{pstyle/.style={\fillgreen}};
    %\node[pstyle] (char) {GREEN};% <<< fails here
 }
 
%% === ERROR 2 ===
 \tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
 \tikzset{pstyle/.style={fill=\choosecolor{true}}};
% \node[pstyle] (char) {CHOOSE COLOR};% <<< fails here
 }

\tikz [% baseline=(char.base), % not used , see comment
        rstl/.style={fill=red},% usual way to do it
        gstl/.style={fill=green}]{
    \node [rstl] at (2,2) {red-1};
    \node [gstl] at (2,3) {green-2};
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The last `tikz` is wrong --- you do not define the `char` name so it's using the one in the last tikz environment... (try to remove all the other `\tikz` and you'll have an error).

Comment: You are correct :)

Comment: @MS-SPO The statement you added is smart, I didn't know this usage, thanks. However it's like a hard coding, is it any possibility using  `fillgreen` and `\choosecolor` ?

Comment: Not that I‘m aware of. See also Rmano‘s nice answer. // You can see these formats throughout the whole pgf manual. Just have a look. You can even define default styles.